# Will Squid fix SSL errors on old Mac OS system (Snow Leopard)?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, openssl, squid

I am trying to keep a Mac OS 10.6.8/Snow Leopard system functionally useful, but for years have been unable to overcome browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari) that refuse to connect to certain HTTPS websites, claiming my system clock is wrong (it is not), or that force me to choose an "advanced" unsafe method to view the site (example: pypi.org), or that refuse to connect with no workaround.

I presume that the old SSL software in the OS is the root problem.  I have tried updating OpenSSL, but that has failed, as detailed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50338873/what-is-the-checklist-for-up-to-date-ssl-tls-on-os-x-snow-leopard).

Having just discovered [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) and [SquidMan](http://squidman.net/index.html), I am wondering if I could install Squid 3.5.28 (via SquidMan 4.0) on my machine and then somehow configure Squid to effectively bypass the problematic SSL software in the OS.  My hope is that Squid comes equipped with its own up-to-date SSL routines that would be used in place of the OS routines.

Due to my thin knowledge of proxies and how they work, and before investing the considerable time and pain it would take to do the Squid experiment, I am hoping to learn from you whether this is an obviously dumb idea. Certainly, if there are alternate strategies, those would be on-topic.

The release notes for [Squid 3.5.28](http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/v3/3.5/squid-3.5.28-RELEASENOTES.html) contain this intriguing sentence: "When Squid is built with the GnuTLS encryption library the tool is able to open TLS (or SSL/3.0) connections to servers."  I'm thinking that might be relevant to my problem.

Comment: I haven't tried any of these, but you might want to look at Arctic Fox, which still supports Snow Leo, or some of the other suggestions on AF's downloads page - https://github.com/wicknix/Arctic-Fox/wiki/Downloads

Comment: Many thanks for the Arctic Fox pointer!  It looks like a very a good start.  However, my problem description failed to state that the issues are more extensive than just the browser.  Python "pip" is also affected, and this is a very large issue.  So my question remains in need of a more general solution.